# Issue in Create new Controller in Zend Framework 2 (ZF2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 Skeleton app.
To create a new controller in a existing Module, I modified the **module.config.php** file like this:

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController', // WORKING FINE
        'Album\Controller\Photo' => 'Album\Controller\PhotoController', // I ADDED THIS
    ),
),

// The following section Was PREVIOUSLY THERE
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
 ),


// ADDED THIS FOR NEW CONTROLLER 'PhotoController.php' in same Namespace 'Album'
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'photo' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/photo[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Photo',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),

),
);`
```

This link **(http://domainname.com/dummy/zend/zf2-tutorial/public/*photo*/index)** is working as expected.

This link **(http://domainname.com/dummy/zend/zf2-tutorial/public/*album*/index)** is not working and showing the following errors:

```
A 404 error occurred Page not found. 
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
```

Comment: Erm, the routes you're doing are identical, there is no way to separate them. Second route probably should be `'route'=>'/photo[/:action][/:id]',`

Comment: This reversed the scenario. Now, the second link is working and first one is showing the error:"A 404 error occurred Page not found. 
The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

Comment: I am using same module(Album) and 2 Controllers(AlbumController.php, PhotoController.php). Is it the problem?

Comment: Please take a look at your `'route' => ''` Statements. Both link to the same route setup, going by the configuration you've posted in this thread. Update your question if you update your code

Comment: Thanks @Sam . I edited the Question. But, now, AlbumController is not working though PhotoController started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're declaring `router` in your config twice, the second one overwrites the first, so only the second route is used.

Your config file should look something like this with both routes inside the same `router` declaration

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController', // WORKING FINE
        'Album\Controller\Photo' => 'Album\Controller\PhotoController', // I ADDED THIS
    ),
),

// The following section Was PREVIOUSLY THERE
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // This is where your new route goes
        'photo' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/photo[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Photo',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),

),
);
```