# How to create new controller in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have developed a website in zend framework version 1.
  now i want to create my another project in zend framework version 2.
  In version 1 whenever we need to create new module, new controller we used to do it with      command line. now when i do it in zf2, i got error 'zf is not defined as external or internal command.'. how do i create module,controller automatically in zf2. i do not know their directory structure in zf2 so would not like to copy paste tutorial controller.

  
   How do i create module,controllers in zf2.

Comment: http://zf2cheatsheet.com/, http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html check here

Comment: This question is rather poor there dozens of examples arround plus if you had read trough the docs you wouldn't need to ask this question in the first place. -1.

Examples on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507492/zend-framework-2-add-new-controller.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020170/issue-in-create-new-controller-in-zend-framework-2-zf2

Comment: @cptnk:when i write command to create project:zftool.phar create project 'D:\xampp\htdocs\zend2' then zftool.phar is opening instead of creating a project.

Comment: put following lines n it will work:zftool.phar create projectD:\xampp\htdocs\zend2  (just removed single quotes from destination name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows as development OS, so
download [zftool](https://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar) and put it on C:/.
Open the console and cd to C:/ then you an try the follow

1) create a zf2 project

zftool.phar create project path/to/project

2) create a new Module

zftool.phar create module ModuleName path/to/my/applicationRoot

3) create a new controller

zftool.phar create controller ControllerName ModuleName path/to/my/applicationRoot

You can discover by yourself all th other functionality just running only zftool.phar on console.

Cheers

Comment: when i write command to create project:zftool.phar create project 'D:\xampp\htdocs\zend2' then zftool.phar is opening instead of creating a project.

Comment: Try to put "php" before the command

php zftool.phar create project path/to/project

Comment: i am getting following error:-Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://C:/zftool.phar/src/ZFTool/Model/Uti
lity.php on line 2
Error during the copy of the files in 'D:\xampp\htdocs\zf2dummy'.

Comment: Can you paste here the exact instruction you are running (complete with path if possible)

Comment: hey thanks a lot :) :), i successfully created new project,run composer.phar, let me also create a controller.i might need help again. after that i ll accept your answer.

Comment: That's good, I am happy for you :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51742/discussion-between-sergio-rinaudo-and-user3143770)